# How can I sync two TextBox control's Text properties?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

If I have two text boxes on a form, how can I make it so that their text properties are perfectly synced? Similar to what would happen if they both processed the same KeyDown event.

Comment: To clarify, do you want to be able to type into either text box, or just one and have the other one replicate the text?

Comment: @DeanOC I'd like to be able to type into both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it this way:

```
        textBox1.TextChanged += (s, _) =>
        {
            if (!textBox2.Focused && textBox1.Text != textBox2.Text)
            {
                textBox2.Text = textBox1.Text;
            }
        };

        textBox2.TextChanged += (s, _) =>
        {
            if (!textBox1.Focused && textBox2.Text != textBox1.Text)
            {
                textBox1.Text = textBox2.Text;
            }
        };
```

Basically I'm responding to the `TextChanged` even on each text box, but making sure that the target text box doesn't have focus and that the text actually has changed. This prevents infinite back-and-forth loop trying to update the text and it makes sure that the current insertion point isn't changed by the text being overwritten.

Comment: Very nice solution. Works perfectly as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that you partially answered your own question, have them both assigned to the same `TextChanged` EventHandler check which textbox has changed then update the Text property of the other one, something like this.

```
private void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (((TextBox)sender).Equals(textBox1)) 
        textBox2.Text = ((TextBox)sender).Text;
    else
        textBox1.Text = ((TextBox)sender).Text;
}
```

---

Modified Code to Keep Carat Position Synced between the two TextBox's , see if this is what you are wanting.

```
private void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox tb = (TextBox)sender;
    if (tb.Equals(textBox1))
    {
        if (textBox2.Text != tb.Text)
        {
            textBox2.Text = tb.Text;
            textBox2.SelectionStart = tb.SelectionStart;
            textBox2.Focus();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (textBox1.Text != tb.Text)
        {
            textBox1.Text = tb.Text;
            textBox1.SelectionStart = tb.SelectionStart;
            textBox1.Focus();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This will put the caret positions out of sync though

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly, that you need the carat positions exactly the same between the two, the caret position will be correct on the box you are typing and the textboxes will have exactly the same text.

Comment: Because what I'll actually end up doing is when the user types into the first text box it will select the second text box and the caret position should be in the same spot.

Comment: @test Modified code to keep the carat synced see if that is what you are looking for

Comment: I can't believe that the OP wants the focus to jump back-and-forth as the user types. Is that really what he wants? And further, this code steals focus if the text is programmatically changed. I don't think the OP is being very clear in his requirements.

Comment: @Enigmativity You are right, he does not give a clear example of what he is wanting. I mainly did it this way because of his statement "when the user types into the first textbox it will select the second"  he did not clarify it any further than that.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply do as follows:

```
bool flag1, flag2;

private void t1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (flag2) return;

    flag1 = true;
    t2.Text = t1.Text;
    flag1 = false;
}

private void t2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (flag1) return;

    flag2 = true;
    t1.Text = t2.Text;
    flag2 = false;
}
```